# How to embed a .map file to an existing exe as a post build event

Tags: visual-studio, exe

I have created a visual studio project, when i build it, i want to embed .map file to an existing exe as a post build event action. Could anyone please help to proceed me.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily append anything to your exe like that:

```
copy your.exe /B + your.map /B your_new.exe
```

Comment: Without getting into `-1` debate, I would like to get an argument against my answer. It *DOES* produce a new **working** executable that contains an embedded .map in it.